# Cannot open MATLAB with sudo on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sudo, matlab

I have MATLAB R2017a installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

From console, I am able to run `matlab`, successfully starting the software. However, if I run `sudo matlab` instead, I get the following error:

```
sudo: matlab: command not found
```

I obtained the same response by running first `sudo su` and then `matlab`.

How is it possible that I can only run it without `sudo`? Is there a `sudo`-specific PATH to update?

Comment: Yes `sudo` has its own `secure_path` - see `man sudoers`. However I **strongly** discourage you from running `matlab` as root (it probably wouldn't work right anyway, because of display authority among other things)

Comment: @steeldriver, Fair point, but I am using a proprietary interface built in Simulink which requires `sudo` rights to communicate via EtherCAT. All other users of this add-on are using `sudo` for the purpose. If you can elaborate your answer a bit I will be happy to accept it. For now, I simply need to go to MATLAB's folder before I run the `sudo matlab` command, but all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `sudo` has its own `secure_path`. From `man sudoers`:

> ```
>  secure_path   Path used for every command run from sudo.  If you don't
>                trust the people running sudo to have a sane PATH environ‐
>                ment variable you may want to use this.  Another use is if
>                you want to have the “root path” be separate from the “user
>                path”.  Users in the group specified by the exempt_group
>                option are not affected by secure_path.  This option is not
>                set by default.
> ```

(note that it **is** set by Ubuntu's default `/etc/sudoers`).

If you decide to modify it, remember to use `visudo` rather than your regular editor to avoid locking yourself out in the event of syntax errors.

A better option might be to create a symbolic link from somewhere that's already on the Ubuntu `sudo` `secure_path` e.g.

```
$ ls -ld $(which matlab)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Apr 11  2017 /usr/local/bin/matlab -> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/matlab
```

Best of all would be to arrange your device permissions so that it is not necessary to run `matlab` as root.